# Debugging Flex via localhost with IntelliJ

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying out IntelliJ and I'm trying to duplicate a run debug setting I have in Flash Builder. To test my app I have a Rails application running locally and I set a 'URL of path to launch' under Run > Debug > Other... (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:3000/design/template/123)

Then I use the [Charles Web Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to map a local SWF file (in bin-debug) to the 'remote' SWF file expected by the URL above. This allows Flash Builder to connect to and debug the SWF as if it was running on the server.

IntelliJ seems to have a similar dialog under Run > Edit Configurations where you can set a Launch URL. Hitting debug does indeed launch that URL however the Flash debugger never connects and the browser crashes.

Am I missing a setting in IntelliJ somewhere?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select this:
[image]

Then launch debug <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Make sure, that your SWF is compiled in debug mode and that you have debug version of Flash Player installed for the browser, you're launching it it.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Is there a way when you launch debug for the browser to automatically gain focus?

Comment: @KreeK I don't think so. You can open any browser with many windows, so it's impossible to guess for IntelliJ where the flash is going to be played.